# Create a Style keeping material features

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How do I create a style to change the color of the **ActionBar** Background and Title keeping **AlertDialog**, **EditText** design and other features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can change the color from the elements.

You have a file 
 `res/values/colors.xml`

Define the color you want(example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="verde">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

Create new colors and assign it. Material is not only the colors, you can change the palette color.